# How can I design these tables to prevent corrupted data where one table's foreign keys' referenced rows must agree?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 4 tables :

```
users
id integer primary_key

questions
id integer primary_key
asker_id references users(id)

answers
id integer primary_key
question_id references questions(id)
answerer_id references users(id)

notifications
id integer primary_key
answer_id references answers(id)
notified_user_id references users(id)
```

How do I enforce the following constraint:

The `notified_user_id` in any notification must be the same as the `asker_id` in the question referenced by the `answer_id` in that notification.

Basically I want to make sure I notify the user that asked the question, not just any other user.

I know I can normalize, but I need `notified_user_id` to exist in notifications.

Comment: Since you insist on keeping it denormalized, just enforce the constraint in your app logic. You can't really have it both ways.

Comment: "I know I can normalize, but I need notified_user_id to exist in notifications" . Why? Why can't you use a select statement to join the tables at runtime? You can use triggers for things like this.but it usually indicates a design issue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid because I think joining 4 tables is expensive.

Comment: More expensive than the support overhead of a system that is more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: Measure the expense.  It will depend on volume.  With a few hundred questions, the expense will be trivial.  With a few billion  questions, you need a very good platform.

Comment: What do you mean, "normalize"? Normalization replaces a table by projections of it that join back to it.

Comment: Normalization here is straightforward: eliminate `notifications` table, add `is_notified` flag (or `notified_at` timestamp) to the `answers` table.

Comment: @Nick I also need to track whether the notification was read or not, so that's why I created the table.

Comment: Again, this is not a reason to create whole table -- just add `notification_is_read` column to `answers`.

Comment: Yes you're right, that makes sense. One more step, if an answer notifies multiple users, that's when I need a table?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know that in this schema you have 1:N relation between answers and notifications (so for each answer, you will be able to have multiple notifications).

If it's not you wanted, just add a column `answerer_is_notified` flag (say, of `boolean` data type) to `answers` table and get rid of `notifications` table.

Second, if you do want to go with this denormalized approach (there are redundant functional dependencies that make you think how to fix the lack of constraints, what is not possible to model with FKs only), let's create a trigger:

```
create or replace function notifications_check_user_id_trigger()
  returns trigger as $$
begin
  if new.notified_user_id <> 
    (select answerer_id from answers where id = new.answer_id)
  then
    raise exception e'answer_id (%) and notified_user_id (%) don\'t match',
      new.answer_id,
      new.notified_user_id;
  end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_50_notifications_check_user_id_trigger
  before insert or update
  on notifications
  for each row execute procedure notifications_check_user_id_trigger()
;
```

p.s. didn't actually check this code, some typos are possible. Next time, PLEASE, provide boilerplate DDL SQL to simplify answering.

Comment: @philipxy There is an obvious FD here: `notifications.notified_user_id` functionally depends on `notifications. answer_id` (`notifications.answer_id` → `answers.question_id` → `questions.asker_id`). Normalization is more than you think, read about it (and at least about 1NF, 2NF, 3NF) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: 1. "there are redundant functional dependencies that make you think how to fix the lack of constraints, what is not possible to model with FKs only" is unintelligible. 2. A FD holds within a table, so your comment misuses "→" between tables. You might be *thinking* of a table that decomposes to these tables; you're unclear. 3. It's not clear what you are referring to by "this denormalized approach" but every table in the question is in 5NF so none are "denormalized". 4. I'd suggest you read your own link, but Wikipedia is full of nonsense re normalization, so see an academic textbook.

Comment: No, I'm not misusing anything. Imagine that you took that structure and filled it with data. The author explicitly stated what is the meaning of `notified_user_id`. Open an "academic book" of your preference (by Date, Ullman, Darwen or smb else) and read how FD is defined. Then try to apply it to the data. Within single table of course. You'll see that there is FD. If you still don't see, I cannot help, sorry :)

Comment: You just confirmed what I conjectured, that you are unclearly trying to refer to FDs that hold in "a table that decomposes to these tables" (while writing  FDs meaninglessly between tables) that you are "thinking of"/"imagining". My other points are also correct. Good luck.

Comment: No, your points are completely wrong -- the data here is denormalized, one column depends on another, this is just a mistake of understanding what FD and NF* are.

Answer (score 0):

> The notified_user_id in any notification must be the same as the asker_id in the question referenced by the answer_id in that notification

Why even have `notified_user_id` in notified? This is redundant given the other tables. The user notified is the asker of the question `answer_id`. You get their id by joining.

If you do want `notified_user_id` then to constrain it declaratively add `question_id` to `notifications`.

```
-- notification *id* is to asker *notified_user_id* re answer *answer_id* to their question *question_id*
notifications
    id integer primary_key
    answer_id
    notified_user_id
    question_id
    (answer_id, question_id) references answers(id, question_id)
    (question_id, notified_user_id) references questions(id, asker_id)
```

Now both `notified_user_id` & `question_id` are redundant, but they are properly constrained.

PS Dropping `notified_user_id` from notifications reduces redundancy, but it's not the kind of redundancy that normalization addresses and the dropping isn't normalization. Also, your (commented) notion of joining when dropping being "expensive" is misconceived.